# How to call other eureka client in a Zuul server

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

application.properties

```
zuul.routes.commonservice.path=/root/path/commonservice/**
zuul.routes.commonservice.service-id=commonservice

zuul.routes.customer.path=/root/path/customer/**
zuul.routes.customer.service-id=customer

zuul.routes.student.path=/root/path/student/**
zuul.routes.student.service-id=student
```

and below is my custom filter

```
import com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter;
import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;
import com.openreach.gateway.common.constant.CommonConstant;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class HeaderFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HeaderFilter.class);

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }
    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        HttpSession httpSession = context.getRequest().getSession();
        String idOrEmail = context.getRequest().getHeader("coustom");

        if (httpSession.getAttribute("someAttributes") == null) {
            if (idOrEmail != null) {
                //call the common-service and get details and set it first
                //then call the customer service with common-service details
            } else {
                //call the customer service
            }

        } else {
            log.info("data excits");
            // routrs the request to the backend with the excisting data details
        }

        context.addZuulResponseHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + httpSession.getId());


        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm using the ribbon load balancer with zuul. My problem is that how should I call the common-service first? I need all my requests to check the header value and then call the actual service end point.

Comment: I think you can use `Feign` client to call `common-service`.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the @LoadBalanced qualifier to create your RestTemplate bean which is load balanced.

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

And Inject the bean into the filter

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Then you can get result by restTemplate's method like below

```
String result = restTemplate.postForObject("http://commonservice/url", object, String.class);
```

ref: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_resttemplate_as_a_load_balancer_client